# How to query service principle details with service principle with Azure python sdk

Tags: azure, azure-service-principal, azureml-python-sdk

I want to query service principle expire datatime with Azure python SDK. I have already a service principle with "GlobalReader" permission. I can authenticate with below code.

```
>>> from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
>>> x=ServicePrincipalAuthentication(tenant_id=tenant_id, service_principal_id=client_id, service_principal_password=client_secret)
>>> dir(x)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_cached_arm_token', '_cached_azureml_client_token', '_cached_graph_token', '_check_if_subscription_exists', '_cloud_type', '_enable_caching', '_get_adal_auth_object', '_get_all_subscription_ids', '_get_aml_resource_id', '_get_arm_end_point', '_get_arm_token', '_get_azureml_client_token', '_get_cloud_suffix', '_get_cloud_type', '_get_graph_token', '_get_service_client', '_get_sp_credential_object', '_get_workspace', '_initialize_sp_auth', '_is_token_expired', '_service_principal_id', '_service_principal_password', '_sp_auth_lock', '_tenant_id', '_token_type_to_field_dict', 'get_authentication_header', 'signed_session']
>>>
>>>
>>> x._get_all_subscription_ids
<bound method ServicePrincipalAuthentication._get_all_subscription_ids of <azureml.core.authentication.ServicePrincipalAuthentication object at 0x7f0a174443d0>>
>>> x._get_all_subscription_ids()
```

How to get other service principle expire details? like `az ad sp credential list --id "[ID]" --query "[].endDate" -o tsv`.

#### UPDATE 1

I think I need to look into `azure-graphrbac` module. I see from [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8900), the debug of `az ad sp crendential list`, there is method `graph_client.applications.list_password_credentials(app_object_id)`, but not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
import requests,json

tenantId = '<tenant id>'

query_SP_object_id = '<object ID of SP you want to query>'

x=ServicePrincipalAuthentication(tenant_id= tenantId , service_principal_id='<sp id>', service_principal_password='<sp secret>')

reqURL = 'https://graph.windows.net/'+tenantId +'/applications/'+ query_SP_object_id +'/passwordCredentials?api-version=1.6'
result = requests.get(reqURL,headers={"Authorization":'Bearer ' + x._get_graph_token()}).text

print(json.loads(result)['value'])
```

Result:
[image]

[image]

Pls note in this case, we use sp object ID:

[image]

Comment: it works. you saved me.